# How to load generated java documentation in swing program

Tags: java, swing, javadoc, windowbuilder

I have a program with a GUI developed in swing. There's a menu item that I want to load my API documentation that I created with javadoc. Anyone possibly know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would the JavaDoc for a GUI be of interest to the user?  Given the simplicity of the generated HTML, it can be displayed in a `JEditorPane`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for an [annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).